# Magento After Login redirection

Tags: magento-1.9

I set Magento After Login redirection No

```
System > Config > Customer > Costumer Redirect Customer to Account Dashboard after Logging in > NO
```

It's working fine in **Mozila Browser** It redirect to Previous page and top link also changed Login into Logout

But In **Chrome Browser** It redirect to Previous page but top link it doesn't change once i manually reload the page then only it change into Logout.

I delete

```
var/cache
var/session
```

But no changes. How do i fix it

Comment: Sounds like a cache issue. Please try in incognito mode on chrome and on another PC

Comment: i tried in incognito mode on chrome same problem

Comment: it is cookie setting issue at ur system..Please set proper cookie setting at magento admin

Comment: how to set cookie seeting